# Reestablishing webrtc connection many times using the initial offer and answer

Tags: webrtc

Is it possible to establish webrtc data connection with certain peer and then close it and then re-establish it again and again without exchanging offers and answers through signalling channel each time? I think about reusing initially generated offer and answer. I don't have any special knowledge in this field but I assume that the problem is how to make a browser always listen to the same known ip port so as to wait for incoming connections, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just 're-establish' the connection. You have to start with offer/answer stage again.

Comment: I can use previously generated offer and answer to make browser start establishing connection.

Comment: Yes, but you can't affect on the browser's behavior. You will send the stored offer - and the opponent browser will generate new answer. You can use the stored answer, but the browser will listen on different ports, etc. So, basically storing answer/offer doesn't make any sense.